# Any way to check if two checkboxes are checked at the same time

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

ive tried using && but it doesnt seem to work, this is what I have right now

```
public void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkbox2.Checked)
    {

    }else if (checkbox3.Checked)
    {

    }else if (checkbox2.Checked && checkbox3.Checked)
    {
        //this doesnt seem to work just executes the code in one of the two if statements above//
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

I want to make it run some code if both of those checkboxes are checked at the same time (checkbox2 and checkbox3)
but the && operator doesnt seem to work for that, atleast in my case

Comment: `else if` means "if the previous clauses where not executed" so you need to reorder

Comment: yeah I got it now thanks

Comment: @Deitznuts debugging your code step by step you would literally see what is happening and then it's really just about thinking about it and waiting for the realization :-D order of execution is really important and so is stepping through the code. I hope Eric's answer will help you in the future to actually go through these steps before raising the question or claiming the && is not working :-D

Comment: @Tomek yeah ill keep this in mind thanks, also I've used the operator before so I know it wasn't the problem but I knew I did something wrong I just couldn't tell what it was that's why I came on here to ask about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with the order of execution.

```
public void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkbox2.Checked && checkbox3.Checked)
    {

    }
    else if (checkbox2.Checked)
    {

    }else if (checkbox3.Checked)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you're a lifesaver thought I was about to start having nightmares about not being able to solve this problem xD